# What is the difference between the [1]forking lemma(David Pointcheval) and the [2]general forking lemma(Mihir Bellare)?

Tags: multi-signature

My course teacher mentioned that the two forking lemmas have different prerequisites for use.
The former [article (Security Arguments for Digital Signatures
and Blind Signature)](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/David-Pointcheval/publication/2551469_Security_Arguments_for_Digital_Signatures_and_Blind_Signatures/links/00b7d5169310329af9000000/Security-Arguments-for-Digital-Signatures-and-Blind-Signatures.pdf) is more limited, but I did not find it in the [second article I read](https://soc1024.ece.illinois.edu/teaching/ece498ac/fall2018/forkinglemma.pdf), and the article did not describe the difference between the two in detail (for example, the article mentioned that [article 1](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/David-Pointcheval/publication/2551469_Security_Arguments_for_Digital_Signatures_and_Blind_Signatures/links/00b7d5169310329af9000000/Security-Arguments-for-Digital-Signatures-and-Blind-Signatures.pdf) is not applicable to multi-signature).

I am not a student of cryptography, so I can't easily understand this problem. Maybe I didn’t understand the article, but I hope to get your answers, thank you!

Comment: Could you link the mentioned article?

Comment: I'm very sorry. Here are two articles:
article[1]:
https://www.researchgate.net/profile/David-Pointcheval/publication/2551469_Security_Arguments_for_Digital_Signatures_and_Blind_Signatures/links/00b7d5169310329af9000000/Security-Arguments-for-Digital-Signatures-and-Blind-Signatures.pdf
article[2]:
https://soc1024.ece.illinois.edu/teaching/ece498ac/fall2018/forkinglemma.pdf
Thanks!